# Password Recovery Control, Submit Button Does Nothing

Tags: asp.net

I have a weird issue with the password recovery control.  When clicking the submit button, nothing happens, it does not go to the next stage which should be the security question.  Its like its not wired up or something.

Here is the code I am using in the web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SAMWEBSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <!-- Add a customized SqlMembershipProvider -->
        <add name="SAMWEBSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SAMWEBConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="AMC" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
      </providers>
</membership>
```

Webpage:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="password-recovery2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server">
</asp:PasswordRecovery>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself.  There was some code interfering with password recovery control.  The offending code:

```
 <script src="script/WaterMark.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id*=UserName], [id*=Password]").WaterMark();

        });
 </script>
```

Thanks anyway.